# How to prevent function call of multiple time to a single time

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a situation where i want to call a `function` only a single `time` but it is `firing` multiple time how to prevent that.

http://jsfiddle.net/pdzTW/224/

```
function howManyTimesIwasCalled(value){
  console.log('i have called so many time '+value);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('please scroll output window and check the console');

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop() + 200;

    $('div').each(function(e) {
      if ($(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > cutoff) {
        $('div').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        howManyTimesIwasCalled($(this).data('value'));

        //callGoogleMapHere(data..);

        return false; // stops the iteration after the first one on 
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling up to parent it does not let you fire a function only once. add all relevant to OP

Comment: ok sorry for `e.stopPropagation()` but do you know any kind of solution

Comment: why so many negative vote i did any crime?

Comment: Can you please explain the scenario more???

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but you should know that `scroll` fires once for every pixel scrolled. That seems to be the source of your problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, sir how can achieve single time firing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/tvv1tqmb/

```
function howManyTimesIwasCalled( value ) {
    console.log( 'i have called so many time ' + value );
}

$( document ).ready( function () {
    alert( 'please scroll output window and check the console' );
    var lastDiv = undefined;
    $( document ).scroll( function () {
        var cutoff = $( window ).scrollTop() + 200;

        $( 'div' ).each( function ( e ) {
            if ( $( this ).offset().top + $( this ).height() > cutoff ) {

                if ( $( this ).data( 'value' ) == lastDiv ) {
                    return false;
                }

                $( 'div' ).removeClass( 'current' );
                $( this ).addClass( 'current' );


                howManyTimesIwasCalled( $( this ).data( 'value' ) );

                //callGoogleMapHere(data..);

                lastDiv = $( this ).data( 'value' );

                return false; // stops the iteration after the first one on 
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: This, however, relies on the `data-value` attributes existing and being unique

Comment: James you deserve everything

Comment: 2 peoples closed my question but you are my hero

Comment: This won't work if you scroll up again.  With the above code, function will be called multiple times if we scroll up and down

Comment: @Vineesh I think this is fine in this instance. He just wanted the function to only execute if the focused div changes.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event and resize event fire multiple times as a user does this. To help prevent this. Use a global boolean to check if the function has fired.

```
var tmp = 0;
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {           
  $(this).scroll(function(){
    if(tmp == 0){
      var self = this, $this = $(self);
      if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
        clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
      }
      $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,300,self));
      tmp = 1;
    }
  });
};


$(window).scrollStopped(function(){
    console.log('Test')
  tmp=0;
})
```